# How does temperature differ from mean kinetic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

If I understand it correctly, temperature is the measure of the average kinetic energy of a substance. Why is it then that $T\neq \bar E_{k}$ or something similar? Why is the kelvin a base unit and temperature a base quantity in The International System of Units (SI)?

Comment: The other question helps, but I am still wondering if can temperature be described only using other physical quantities and is there a need for a special unit such as the kelvin?

Comment: What are the boxes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean

Comment: I see three box characters in your equation. Maybe it is a rendering problem that happens only in some browsers. (I’m looking at it in Safari on an iPad.) It’s happening because you didn’t use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your math.

Comment: sorry, i will fix it. it is supposed to say T is not equal to E (with a subscipt ''k, mean'')